# Non-Galois number fields and complex embeddings

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let
$K$
be a number field.
$K$
is a *normal* extension of
$\mathbb{Q}$
iff
$\exists f(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]: K$
is the splitting field for
$f(x)$.
A field extension is *Galois* iff it is normal and separable, but since all number fields are separable extensions of 
$\mathbb{Q}$,
normal and Galois coincide in this case.
I also recall a theorem saying Galois number fields must have either all totally real or all complex infinite places (embeddings).

A common example is
$K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.
I understand why this is not normal: it lacks the complex cube roots of 2.
But what if we instead extend
$\mathbb{Q}$
by one of the complex roots?

Consider the case where
$K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3\sqrt[3]{2})$,
where
$\zeta_3$
is the primitive cube root of unity.
This is a degree 3 extension of
$\mathbb{Q}$,
with 2 of those degrees corresponding to the identity/conjugation complex place.
Since complex places contribute multiples of 2 to the degree, the remaining 1 must correspond to a real place (in particular, having as image the field in the previous paragraph), meaning 
$K$
cannot be normal.
But 
$K$ 
is the splitting field for 
$x^3-2$,
*[Note: $K$ is not the splitting field - that was the nature of the confusion here. -JQ]*.
which is the minimal polynomial of
$\zeta_3\sqrt[3]{2}$, is it not?

In general I'd like to understand the case of number fields with exactly 1 complex place, and at least 1 real place.  I'm able to produce lots of examples, but I don't get why they are not considered normal.

Comment: I don't understand your argument, but anyway, $K$ is *not* the splitting field, as it does not contain the real cubic root of $2$.

Comment: I think this answers my question in that case.  I overlooked that $K$ doesn't include the real cube root.  So the splitting field is actually $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta_3\sqrt[3]{2})$? The problem is I don't know enough about non-Galois field extensions.  What is the primitive element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta_3\sqrt[3]{2})$?

Comment: Some linear combination over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\zeta_3$, by the primitive element theorem.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.

Comment: Hopefully you know about this, but just in case: $K$ itself is not closed under complex conjugation. It contains only one of the roots of $p(x)=x^3-2$. Also, if $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$ are the three zeros of $p(x)$, then all the fields $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha_i)$, $i=1,2,3$, are isomorphic to each other (and to $\Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$). Thus it would be surprising if they had a different set of embeddings to $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: Oh, and Galois theory tells you that $z=\root3\of2+\zeta_3$ is a primitive element. For all non-identity automorphisms $\sigma\in Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2,\zeta_3)/\Bbb{Q})$ we have $\sigma(z)\neq z$. Thus $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2,\zeta_3)/\Bbb{Q}(z))$ is trivial, so by Galois correspondence $\Bbb{Q}(z)=\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2,\zeta_3)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In general I'd like to understand the case of number fields with exactly 1 complex place, and at least 1 real place. I'm able to produce lots of examples, but I don't get why they are not considered normal.

One of the several possible equivalent definitions of "Galois," for a number field $K$, is that every embedding $K \to \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ has the same image. (If $K$ is the splitting field of some polynomial $f$, then this image is generated by the roots of $f$.) Composed with the natural map $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} \to \mathbb{C}$, yet another equivalent is that every embedding $K \to \mathbb{C}$ has the same image. In particular, either they're all contained in $\mathbb{R}$ or none of them are.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that; you phrase it nice and concisely though.  Since posting the question, I've remembered a lot of what I'd forgotten about Galois theory - it had been a while.